# Can I ask for an option to relocate in my contract

Tags: contracts, relocation

I live in the UK and have received an offer from another company. This company has offices in London and Paris among others.

I am French and thinking about relocating to Paris, is it possible (I mean enforceable) to have a clause in the contract that would say something like "the employee should be relocated to Paris should he wish to" (potentially with covenants like after 2 years if the office is still opened etc...)

Comment: You can put anything in a contract that you would like.  I am hard-pressed to imagine a company agreeing to such a term however.  If they do similar work in the two offices, and two years from now you want to do an internal transfer to an open role in the Paris office, most companies would be at least open to that.  But if the Paris office doesn't have an opening in two years for someone who does exactly what you do, no one is going to want to commit themselves to creating an opening just for you.

Comment: it is not really an "opening" I could do what I do in any place. There would be just a relocation... but this means changing the contract to a french contract

Comment: You'll have to ask them

Comment: It should probably be worded like "the employee shall be given the option to relocate to Paris..." If you want to **make** the employer offer it to you, or "the employee may be given the option..." if you want the employer to have the option of offering it to you. There is a big legal distinction between shall/will/may... You also need to think of the expense you are obligating on the employer and if they are going to believe its worth hiring you for that extra cost.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make them add to the contract. There is indeed an extra cost as cost of employment is higher in France than in the UK

Comment: What do you expect from the employer 6 months-2 years down the road? Do you expect them to guarantee you a relocation offer to Paris when you've decided to move? Or do you just want to be *considered* for relocation? If you just want to be considered, then there is no reason to add something extra to the contract.

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible (I mean enforceable) to have a clause in the contract

Yes, you can write anything you want into a contract. Getting the other party to sign it is the problem. And I can't think why any company would agree to such a thing, or even let you modify their contract in such a way.

Comment: Because they want me to sign with them???

Comment: Rien d'impossible

Comment: @statquant: are you sufficiently unique that they won't just hire the next guy on the list? Probably not...